# Unable to update Google Chrome stable on Ubuntu LTS 12.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-12.04

When attempting to run `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`, I'm presented with the following message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installable
                        Depends: lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.6) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I attempt to install `lib32gcc1` for example, I get the message

```
Package lib32gcc1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lib32gcc1' has no installation candidate
```

1. What is causing the issue i.e. why are the packages broken?
2. How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you installed all aviable update for 12.04?

Comment: Yes, is your 12.04 up to date?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304017

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes

Comment: @Seth - Yes it is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a packaging bug in the Chrome repository.

You may use [this solution](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304017) from the chromium bug tracker until the Google-chrome-stable package is updated on the repository.

You can repackage and install it like so:

```
$ apt-get download google-chrome-stable
$ dpkg-deb -R google-chrome-stable_30.0.1599.101-1_i386.deb 304017
$ sed -i 304017/DEBIAN/control \
  -e 's/30.0.1599.101-1/30.0.1599.101-2~304017/' \
  -e 's/lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.6), //' \
  -e 's/libc6-i386 (>= 2.11), //'

$ sudo chown root:root 304017/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
$ sudo chmod 4755 304017/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox

$ dpkg-deb -b 304017
$ sudo dpkg -i 304017.deb
```

Credits goes to this [user](https://code.google.com/u/pdknsk/).

Comment: Today I upgraded Chrome with my regular package manager without any problem. Seems that the google-chrome-stable package has been updated in the repo, fixing the packaging issue. Maybe this question can be closed?

Comment: I'm still having issues using apt-get.